# HTML Table getting data from mysql database using php. I can't seem to be figuring out how to print that data using my js code to put it into a form

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

*(my final 2 images don't have a hyperlink cause i can only post a max of 2, i have added 2 spaces that you can take out to look at my screenshots)*

I am working on a website for a company, I am almost finished but I am stuck on the last tiny bit which I have researched hard. I have made a html table that gets information from a mysql database as seen below.
[HTML Table fetching data from mysql database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBSM9.png)

I have made a js code that once i click on a row in the table it prints the data into the *print page* as seen below.

[This is the print page with some notes to clarify my picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySMpv.png)

Here is my javascript code for the print function .

```
<script>
   function printContent(el){
       var restorepage = document.body.innerHTML;
       var printcontent = document.getElementById(el).innerHTML;
       document.body.innerHTML = printcontent;
       printcontent {transform: scale(1.5);}
       window.print();
       document.body.innerHTML = restorepage;
   }
</script>
```

This is the button corrosponding with my print function:

```
<div>
   <button class="submit" name="submit" id="submit" onclick="printContent('div1')">Print</button>
</div>
```

This is my javascript code that takes the Table data and puts it into my *print page*

```
<div id="printoverzicht">
<?php

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM palletlabel WHERE $kwekersnummer = kwekersnummer";

    $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    if (!$query) {
        die ('SQL Error: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
    }

    mysqli_close($conn);
?>


<br><br><br><h1>Eerdere Print Opdrachten</h1>
 <table class="data-table" id="table">
    <caption class="title">Klik op de gewenste printopdracht om te printen</caption>
      <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>palletnummer</th>
            <th>kwekersnummer</th>
            <th>plukdatum</th>
            <th>aanleverdatum</th>
            <th>aantal</th>
            <th>excelartikel</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
    {
        echo '<tr>
                <td>'.$row['palletnummer'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['kwekersnummer'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['plukdatum'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['aanleverdatum'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['aantal'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['excelartikel'].'</td>
                </tr>';

    }  
    ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
    <script>

            var table = document.getElementById('table');

            for(var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++)
            {
                table.rows[i].onclick = function()
                {
                     //rIndex = this.rowIndex;
                     document.getElementById("palletnummer1").value = 
                      this.cells[0].innerHTML;
                     document.getElementById("plukdatum1").value = 
                      this.cells[2].innerHTML;
                     document.getElementById("aanleverdatum1").value = 
                      this.cells[3].innerHTML;
                     document.getElementById("aantal1").value = 
                      this.cells[4].innerHTML;
                     document.getElementById("artikel1").value = 
                      this.cells[5].innerHTML;
                };
            }

     </script>
</div>
```

This is the *print page - form* , where the information needs to get put in. This is labeled as div1 so that its being called by the button.

```
        <div id="div1" class="Palletlabel">
          <hr color="#BDBDBD" width="600">
        <div id="inner"><b>Kweker</b></div>
          <hr color="#BDBDBD" width="600">
        <div class = "palletkweker">
        <div class = "palletkwekerlinks">
            <br><b>Bedrijfsnaam: </b><br><?php echo $bedrijfsnaam;?>
            <br><b>Straat+nr: </b><br><?php echo $straat;?> <?php echo 
              $huisnummer;?>
            <br><b>Plaats: </b><br><?php echo $plaats;?>
            <br><b>Postcode: </b><br><?php echo $postcode;?>
            <br><b>Aanmaakdatum - (backup print): </b><?php echo 
              date('m/d/Y'); ?>
        </div>
        <div class = "palletkwekerrechts">
            <br><b>Milieukenmerk: </b><br><?php echo $ggn;?>
            <br><b>Fair produce: </b><br><?php echo $fairproduce;?>
            <br><b>GGN: </b><br><?php echo $milieukeurmerk;?>
            <br><b>SKAL: </b><br><?php echo $skal;?>
            <br><b>Overig: </b><br><?php echo $overigkeurmerk;?>
        </div>
        </div>

           <hr color="#BDBDBD" width="600">
        <div id="inner"><b>Champignons</b></div>
           <hr color="#BDBDBD" width="600">
        <div class = "champignons">
        <div class = "champignonslinks">
            <p></p><br><br>
            <p><b>Palletnummer:</b></p>
            <p><textarea disabled name="textarea" id="palletnummer1" 
             name="palletnummer1"><?php echo $_GET['Palletnummer'];?> 
             </textarea></p>
            <p><b>Plukdatum:</b></p>
            <p><textarea disabled name="textarea" id="plukdatum1" 
             name="plukdatum1"><?php echo $_GET['Plukdatum'];?> </textarea>
            </p>
            <p><b>Aantal:</b></p>
            <p><textarea disabled name="textarea" id="aantal1"><?php echo 
             $_GET['Aantal'];?></textarea></p>
            <p><b>Gewicht:</b></p>
            <p><textarea disabled name="textarea" id="gewicht1"></textarea>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class = "champignonsrechts">
               <p></p><br><br>
               <p><b>Aanleverdatum:</b></p>
               <p><textarea disabled name="textarea" id="aanleverdatum1"><?
                php 
                echo $_GET['Aanleverdatum'];?></textarea></p>
               <p><b>Excel Artikel / L.V.O:</b></p>
               <p><textarea disabled name="textarea" id="artikel1"><?php 
                echo 
                $_GET['Artikel'];?></textarea></p>
               <p><b>Vlucht:</b></p>
               <p><textarea disabled name="textarea" id="vlucht1"><?php echo 
                $_GET['Vlucht'];?></textarea></p>
               <p><b>Vluchtdag:</b></p> 
               <p><textarea disabled name="textarea" id="vluchtdag1"><?php 
                echo 
                $_GET['Vluchtdag'];?></textarea></p>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class = "palletbottum">



           <hr color="#BDBDBD" width="600">
        <div id="inner"><b>Afleveradres</b></div>
           <hr color="#BDBDBD" width="600">

        <div class ="pallettop">
           <p>Limax BV<br> Venrayseweg 126b <br> Horst <br> 5960AJ </p>
        </div>
</div>
</div>
```

This print function has worked for my first page aswell, but it is not pushing the javascript info through that the function is pushing in like shown in these 2 pictures.

As you can see in this picture the data gets pushed into the *print page*

https: //i.stack.imgur.com/ pOSBM.png

This is what I see when I click print

As you can see here the data that went into the *print page* did not come through in the print screen https: //i.stack.imgur.com/ waCJp.png

As seen in the last image the data that I managed to get into the *print page* does not come through in the print screen which is what I am stuck with. I have been googling, going through forums etc to find out what this caused but I can not seem to be figuring it out.

I need to make it able that once you click the print button it also comes out with the info i got into the *print page* because having the info in the print page but it not printing it has no value for me. I need the companies their suppliers to be able to print the data we need.

I hope someone would be able to help me with the data i provided, if you need extra data please ask so.

I have put alot of time into this post so I hope I won't get put on hold again or be turned down negative.

Tom.

### --EDIT - SOLUTION --

```
    <script>
      function printContent(el){
         var restorepage = $('body').html();
         var printcontent = $('#' + el).clone();
         var enteredtext = $('#text').val();
         $('body').empty().html(printcontent);
         window.print();
         $('body').html(restorepage);
         $('#text').html(enteredtext);
      }
    </script>
```